# getting top post from Facebook for iPhone

Tags: iphone, facebook

I have a very different requirement in my app.Using the app i need to get top 25 most liked and most commented posts from facebook.First let me ask the experts does it seems to be possible till today?
As far as i thought and researched on this I am able to get the likes and comments for a page(of an organization or celebrity using graph api).
My approach was to make an Admin panel and subscribe most of the famous people,organization,product etc,but this won't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not possible to do I'm afraid. From what you are asking, you want to find the most popular posts across all of facebook? This is most likely going to come from Pages as these are public and can have millions of people liking / commenting on posts.

Either way, this would be a complex and data-intensive task. You would have to scrape posts from all the top Facebook pages and see which ones would have the most links / comments. A lot of work for little reward.

Comment: :-I agree data wud be much more for this case but even with that case it is not possible right?
Atmost i can do is getting likes and comments for each popular pages,right?

Comment: I theory, is it possible to do, but it means finding and processing lots of data across facebook. You are better off selecting a few pages to focus on and looking at the links / comments on those posts.

Comment: Can you please tell me how do you think it's possible?How can i access the post of a particular user to get the likes of that?
Even though i do it for a particular page i cannot get the likes and comments per post,isn't it.I can get overall likes and posts.

Comment: You won't be able to do this for users, as you will need access to read the user's stream, which can only be done if they authorise your app.

For pages, you can use a App Access Token to get the post, and see the Likes / Comments for the posts. `likes` and `comments` objects are returned for each post. Give it a try and see for yourself.

Comment: I have tried this but i am only able to get overall likes and comment for a particular page.Can you give me a hint how to go about that?

Comment: Isn't the overall likes / comments enough for ranking a post? You don't need to see who actually liked / commented it...